# Find strings from one file that are not in lines of another file

Tags: string, awk

In a bash shell script, I need to create a file with strings from file 1 that are not found in lines from file 2. File 1 is opened through a for loop of files in a directory.

```
files=./Output/*
for f in $files
do

done
```

I have very large files, so using grep isn't ideal. I previously tried:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$2]=$0;next}!($2 in A){print }' file2 file1 > file3
```

file 1:

```
NB551674:136:HHVMJAFX2:1:11101:18246:1165
NB551674:136:HHVMJAFX2:1:11101:10296:1192
NB551674:136:HHVMJAFX2:1:11101:13281:1192
NB551674:136:HHVMJAFX2:2:21204:11743:6409
```

file 2:

```
aggggcgttccgcagtcgacaagggctgaaaaa|AbaeA1    NB551674:136:HHVMJAFX2:2:21204:11743:6409   100.000 32  0   0   1   32  83  114 7.30e-10    60.2 
taccaacaattcagcgttacgccaacggtaac|AbaeB1 NB551674:136:HHVMJAFX2:4:21611:6341:1845    100.000 32  0   0   1   32  27  58  6.70e-10    60.2 
taccaacaattcagcgttacgccaacggtaac|AbaeB1 NB551674:136:HHVMJAFX2:4:11504:1547:13124   100.000 32  0   0   1   32  88  119 6.70e-10    60.2 
taccaacaattcagcgttacgccaacggtaac|AbaeB1 NB551674:136:HHVMJAFX2:3:11410:11337:15451  100.000 32  0   0   1   32  27  58  6.70e-10    60.2
```

expected output:

```
NB551674:136:HHVMJAFX2:2:21204:11743:6409
```

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: You're example would be more useful if some of the lines from file1 matched some lines from file2 and you showed the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `comm`, which requires sorted files. Print the second field of file2 using a Perl one-liner (or `cut`):

```
comm -23 <(sort file1) <(perl -lane 'print $F[1]' file2 | sort)
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close - file1 only has 1 field ($1) but you were trying to use $2 in the hash lookup (`$2 in A`). Do this instead:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]; next} !($1 in a)' file2 file1
NB551674:136:HHVMJAFX2:1:11101:18246:1165
NB551674:136:HHVMJAFX2:1:11101:10296:1192
NB551674:136:HHVMJAFX2:1:11101:13281:1192
```

Don't use all upper case for user-defined variable names in awk or shell btw to avoid clashes with builtin variables and other reasons.

Answer (score -2):

don't do that one line left compare one line right mess.

use gawk in bytes mode, or preferably, mawk, preload every single line into an array from file 1. use the strings directly as the array's hash indices instead of just numerical 1,2,3....

and set FS same as ORS (to prevent it from unnecessarily attempt to process the string looking to split fields).

close file 1. open file 2, then use each of the strings in file 2 and delete the corresponding entry in the array.

close file 2.

in END section, print out whatever is left inside that array. that's your set.